# How to specify the type for the return of useNavigation

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm having some diffuculties specifing the parameters for a function (`onError`) that receive the return of a `useNavigation()`)

```js
import { BottomTabScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { CompositeScreenProps, NavigatorScreenParams, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { NativeStackNavigationProp, NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import { AxiosError } from 'axios'

declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
  }
}

export type RootStackParamList = {
  SignIn: undefined
  ResetPassword: { email: string }
  Tabs: NavigatorScreenParams<TabsParamList> | undefined
  Modal: undefined
  Error: { error: AxiosError | string } | undefined
}

export type TabsParamList = {
  Overview: NavigatorScreenParams<OverviewParamList> | undefined
  Allocation: undefined
  Menu: NavigatorScreenParams<MenuParamList> | undefined
}

export type OverviewParamList = {
  OverviewRoot: undefined
  Deposit: undefined
}

export type MenuParamList = {
  MenuRoot: undefined

  UserProfile: undefined
  // other settings
}

export type RouteName = keyof RootStackParamList | keyof OverviewParamList | keyof TabsParamList | keyof MenuParamList

export const routeTypeGuard = (route: RouteName) => route as keyof RootStackParamList

export type RootStackScreenProps<Screen extends keyof RootStackParamList> = NativeStackScreenProps<
  RootStackParamList,
  Screen
>

export type RootTabScreenProps<Screen extends keyof TabsParamList> = CompositeScreenProps<
  BottomTabScreenProps<TabsParamList, Screen>,
  NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>
>


export function useErrorHandling() {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  // navigation.replace() // this throws a type error - which seems right

  return { onError: (error: unknown) => onError(navigation, error) } // how to avoid this to throw an error ??
}

export function onError(
  nav: ReturnType<typeof useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>>,
  error: unknown
) {
  // nav.replace // does not throw type error, but experienced it to make the app crash because nav.replace was undefined
  nav.navigate('Error', { error: error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknow error' })
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgIQjGEQBUCGAjAZQGMoBTUgOwAUoIwBnOAXzgDNaQ4ByAATJyIwAtBRwA3YAHMcMYBAoB6PGgwghMfPS4AoUJFiI4AYUyR6wGKWJlKNOvQA0cAHLipM6NfLUcUHCEc4AFd6UlcJaVl5ZjYObj5SAWFRCJk5RVFZMVIdPWh4JFcsqw0iAGtw9yjqWjAnIuBsglKyr1taxhZ2THj%20QRE3SPSFTMbSIXoW3PB8wwBBAA85egBRKFooGO7OLhwliC1tbQATUiIAG19SOElziDwcc8RtODhREFJ6MAFrgCVEwSVIbRBAvV5wYAUSxQVg-OC-CBoKi%20fwAGWAkzgpAWlgox0YCLQzQEZWRfhA6MxCCYYJpNO02P08BgAE8wH9ETBieUyWiMfAALzPV4EKQUACSFAAXME8aRWJDSMcwf9QjBkfR6AB3aDHGVIUggHDAc4yyZQSGSZhg3B4egyoEeKBtHzk%20gAHlt9F5FP5AD44AAfWWnBUUJVggCyEGOjxlQTlYYjrzWG31WPW0Bli2WqegQbg5stMWDCdDiuV9MZs1Z7LgXp9lMFwrgAHlslAJKQtQ7Bk6XT6Pe3SJ3gN3G-6C2X5RWwXNznciGl5PHE7PXpHKEFe6kMM6SN5B%207NxQghPJgHS2vw5WjtWDLXrsPR%20OUb7MULQa9n12tYSYKu5Y3mCAAipBmBYgEzsBVYLEycCPnAJ5nm%20TZwJ%20UZbv%20UFJsqYIAKqhFAdgKucpA4eucAKAocBoAAFiOhakOglr0NosHwYhCJBJYrgfOhcBlKQLIQKw8KctypKofyBZCSJYk-mOWrnvAwZyaJ9aaCpsnCRpyEqXecGzEQ8iYrQPGkFgbKkAA4kEvjHAJAAU5mWDK3G8f4pAAJToQGrnXDgjDqWJ-6SQZDJGQ%201niUSLQDh07ouliOKUPigm6aFEktCpAZCg0TTxQe7T2O6KrZSSKkOGCLraH6hmcTF-62glpXJdiuLpSFml2rlAkmDM5iWK1DBla8qDoJgLXFTUpUNtJkxOC6frVa8BUlCSI0emFOULTA9X1Q1sysAmgjpMEoR5lAAASOB4uclpOb5X5wCZFCYikVTnUKIRhH21RPWC1FvP96QAHRkGAlxEKQT1UTRMB0RiCF0bQWqMDgCExSOGxwEIcBakjRB0UxhqMBakh0TARyvGQMBBFAFCGPIV0yk5ONZrKZQUBAWoUL5AoBizmZQE5n3AhQTgc1AvksMDdG8whEBwOIEDAI5iPIxgKNoyrTPS3AAD8hvsUdBgnRQZ3RMLGxOWCKTucxDMUFZ7Luo%20Gm-Y61Tuutkne%20kdhgO6O2VXtfoR6tGZplzPN89oz1AzRKQQ%20B0PXMDxwQJ8bxoDriuIdLTh4DxKXshalAw45FhK3ARpCSjgVgGAr1%20PQJN4GcOC-SDYip1DcJakFIbQcmvdg%20LMiw1wV1cE4BoizKBuQpMd0wxpV1G9H0Bgx8mo4JI1wylw%20EUNzivS1wzDeabQA)

Comment: What's the definition of `RootStackParamList` and what's the type error? With a minimal definition for `RootStackParamList` the code type checks: https://tsplay.dev/wQxBGW

Comment: @Oblosys thank you very much for trying to help me out. Sorry for the lack of context in the question. I have updated the question to show how "complex" the navigation tree can be. Basically I wish to navigate to the Error screen from whatever screen - without having a back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not personally worked with `@react-navigation`, so I'm going by the types only, but it looks like `useNavigation`, when called without type parameters, defaults to `ReactNavigation.RootParamList` which doesn't match your `RootStackParamList`. The non-extistent `replace` method comes from the use of `NativeStackNavigationProp` rather than the default `NavigationProp`.

If you specify type parameters `RootStackParamList` and `keyof RootStackParamList` for `useNavigation` and replace `NativeStackNavigationProp` with `NavigationProp` (from `'@react-navigation/core'`), it type checks correctly:

```
export function useErrorHandling() {
  const navigation =
    useNavigation<NavigationProp<RootStackParamList, keyof RootStackParamList>>()

  // navigation.replace() // Error: Property 'replace' does not exist on type ..

  return { onError: (error: unknown) => onError(navigation, error) }
}
```

Additionally, you could simplify the `nav` argument type for `onError` a little bit by using `NavigationProp<RootStackParamList, keyof RootStackParamList>` instead of the `ReturnType` application:

```js
export function onError(
  nav: NavigationProp<RootStackParamList, keyof RootStackParamList>,
  error: unknown
) {
  nav.navigate('Error', { error: error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknow error' })
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgIQjGEQBUCGAjAZQGMoBTUgOwAUoIwBnOAXzgDNaQ4ByAATJyIwAtBRwA3YAHMcMYBAoB6PGgwghMfPS4AoUJFiI4AOXFSZc6rTDM2Hbn1IDhoidNnyFRaKR17o8JABhTEh6YBhSYjJKGjp6ABpjUzdoKPJqHCgcEAS4AFd6UhNXc3kbdkx7fkERZNLFUVkxH11wf0MTJsiNIgBrNJirRhYKzl5q5zr3BvNmoXoe3t82gyQAQQAPOXoAUShaKHK7LhwtiC1tbQATUiIAG0zSOEk7iDwcO8RtODhREFJ6GABE8AEqOQTFMzTL4-H7ACgRKCsYFwEEQNBUTLZAAywAWcFIGwiFCujDRaAIi0xWRAuPxCCY32Y2kZ2kJ+ngMAAnmBQeiYJSBL1qTi8fAALwwuAEKQUACSFAAXPkSaRWPDSFcmWDCjBMfR6AB3aBXZVIUggHDAO7KhZQeGSZk-XB4ejKyEpKADDI0+gAHhd9BFtLFAD44AAfFU3dUUTVMgCyECuH2VeVVsfjPz2BzNBP20GVm22OegkbgdodNij6ZjGq1rPZ7W5vLggeDdIlUoA8s0oBJSIb3VNUiR0sH-b3SP3gIOO2Hy7W1fWmWs7q8iPU0xmVz8E5Q8sOShgvWOYlicn79xQ8vOFuGazu4w3Lk2DC2nlOZ3OL524JKECZL8B0NckYG3OtnyZAARUhQnCCDlygxsNg5OAPzga9b1-MV-ylLCwMQzMtSZABVQooFidU7lIIjdzgBQFDgNAAAtpwrUh0AdegWVfVDmx5Pk8giEx-jw3pSC5CBWFRflBT6O94CjCSpJk4DZ0NRTyxU6S200LTlMk3SsMUvi0K8Ch8VoYTSCwQSAHE8kyK48IACmsiJlTRGzRNIABKf9ww8p4cEYHSZLA+ThRwhYzIE1tIsWb1YgYP1vQJIlKFJOBwtkikqRimBw0lTpgGaKLkqGP1tTkgqaU7eImW9bRQzi99BLymAXUquI0rPCgMuJbLcvbQrirgYI2jCCIetSplUHQTBuv6lL-VG+qxUSb1Q0an5SvKpKVqqxKhUU1rWrZfiDFYdNBAsfJClLKAAAkcBJO4HVcgLAJ+Cz8RcKF7vFJkfgKIopgsP0PXqFK-ROhTCsSXL4eijb71DL7Lh+Rjfgh+QADoyDAB4iFIL6GKYp7lRS6duW4ImSZ8OArggAFfjQDLcLKDD8fxrG4DIGA8igAakHkKm4Fc6dcxVXoKAgQ0KAC8Vw3FgsoFcgG3AsRJpegALGRQtCbooO6yjVg5XKZFwj0B+RYZRxSkaMiLatOsbdvzGX0zlhWKG0b7rfEfGtZkMmuCerhEnNdXlT1w54QWN7Sd0p64AAfi96B8f+A0cEkJ5lS4UiKF9w0s6gLhmD83igA)

Comment: when trying the TS playground I see that it still things that `nav.replace` exist - which does not exist

Comment: The `replace` came from the `NativeStackNavigationProp` type, whereas `useNavigation` returns a `NavigationProp`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: that's some pretty hardcore typescript skills you got  thx a ton

Answer (score 1):

Although this might not be the complete answer, here's a workaround to avoid the error:

```js
const navigation = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<any>>()
```

Comment: that does not give a type error when doing `navigation.replace()`